# Coding help in R - Subset and colSum is the topic

Tags: r, subset, apply, col

The dataframe df is

```
 chr    Name   FLD0195  FLD0197 FLD0201 FLD0203 FLD0211   FLD0243
 chr1    ABC       34    52       29        18    13       30
 chr1    XYZ       44   111       88        65    40       66
 chr1    XYZ        0    0         1         1    0         0
 chr1    ABC        1    0         5         0    0         0
```

What I am looking for is an single line code where it can subset df based on df$name and do the colSum based on the name.

In two line I can do that -

```
  first <- subset(df, df$name=='ABC')
  firstsum <- colSum(first[,3:8])
```

This will give me the result, but if I have say 20 or 30 different names I want to get the colSum in an easy way rather writing 60 lines in case of 30 different names (2 lines of code per name).

Could someone help me with a simple function or is there a single line code I can use instead of two line code ??

Any help will be great.. Thanks..!!

Comment: You can use `%in%` i.e. `subset(df, Name %in% c("ABC", "XYZ"))`

Comment: Or write a small function  `fun <- function(name) colSums(df[df$Name%in%name,3:8])` and put it inside `lapply`: `lapply(c("ABC","XYZ"),fun)`

Comment: Thank you @count 2.. That was quick.. :-)

Comment: @akrun - That was just the subset part, I was looking for colSum along with subset..

Comment: I think you are looking for a group by operation i.e. `aggregate(.~Name, df[-1], sum)`